# Any way to make a top 5 in java displaying the variable names?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jframe, jtextfield

I've been trying to make and display in JFrame a top five out of 13 options. It goes something like this:

I have a .txt with a bunch of words, let's say apple, banana, orange, etc. And a counter for each word. 
Then I open the file and scan it with a Scanner and a String, if it finds the word "apple" then it adds 1 to the apple counter. After it scans the whole .txt I put the counters in an array and sort them with Arrays.sort(array);

My problem is that the array only holds the numeric value for each word, so I tried comparing the last position in the array (since it's the highest one) with every counter for each word, and if it matches with any counter I set that one as "Top 1", then I do the same for "Top 2" and the second-to-last in the array and so on.

But this obviously only works if there are no repeated values. If "Apple" and "Orange" both appear 3 times then both will match and then, the program will set the first one matched in the TextField1 and 2.

Is there a way to go around this? Maybe a way to display the variable name in the TextField instead of the value? or maybe a different data structure to keep both the name and the value of the variable?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> or maybe a different data structure to keep both the name and the value of the variable?

Ding ding! You want to use a map for this. A map stores a key and a value as a pair. To give you a visual representation, a map looks like this:

```
Cats: 5
Dogs: 3
Horses: 2
```

Using a map you can access both the key (name of the word you found) and its paired value (number of times you found it in your file)

[How to use maps](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/map.html#implementations)

Comment: Thanks, i'll try this and report back!

Comment: Yes, I managed to do it with a TreeMap. Thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider priority queue in java. But first you need a class which have 2 attributes (the word and its quantity). This class should implement Comparable and compareTo method should be overridden. Here's an example: https://howtodoinjava.com/java/collections/java-priorityqueue/